# Bitwise rotation with AND, OR, XOR gates

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, boolean-logic

How would one rotate a 4 bit binary number 4 places using only AND, OR, XOR gates?

The inputs could be called `x_0`, `x_1`, `x_2`, `x_3` where `x_3` is MSB and `x_0` is LSB.

For example `1010` rotated right 4 places would be `0101`.

I can't seem to find any sources to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A 4-bit number rotated 4 bits in either direction is the same number you started with.  I think someone is playing a joke on you.

Actually what you showed is *bit-reversing* the number, not rotating it.

To implement a bit-reverser as a combinatorial function, you need 4 pieces of wire. Connect Input[i] to Output[3-i].

To implement it as a state machine, use gates to implement 4 clocked D-type flip flops (see [the Wikipedia page for a diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29).  Connect Input[i] to Output[3-i].

Answer (score 0):

Since you are moving 4 positions a 4 bit binary number, you get the same number.

For example, if you have the binary number 1000, the rotations will be:

1st: 0100 - 
2nd: 0010 - 
3rd: 0001 - 
4th: 1000

As you can see, after 4 rotations you get the same number. Then you don't need any AND, OR, XOR gate.